# wamp server is not working when i open my project

Tags: wamp

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: So.... What;s your question? What have you doen to try and fix it? What did you do just before this error message was displayed?

Comment: Try to look into the error placed at wamp/logs/ directory, Are your other projects running..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using WAMP , i think you have to open **rewrite-module** of apache.
try it , i think it will work.
same problem was with me.